# Algorithm to find frequency of communications network traffic

Tags: python, algorithm, network-programming, statistics, fft

I am writing an algorithm to identify anomalous network traffic by the frequency that it communicates during a day. For example, being able to detect malware by the characteristic that it beacons home regularly, which is different than a normal user's traffic.

characteristics that I'm searching for
* beaconing home at regular intervals
* beaconing home across a longer period of time than a normal user is active, etc.

This gets a little challenging, because often multiple users that may be infected with malware are hidden behind a firewall (they have the same IP address). It seems like I might be able to apply an FFT to search for specific frequencies within a data set, but I haven't been able to find anything similar searching online.

The data that I have available includes
* epoch time (second that outbound communication occurred)
* user IP address 
* destination URL

Below is an example. At the top, you see each second of a day, and malware attempting to beacon back fairly regularly (~2k times per day in this case, likely multiple infections) across a 24 hour period.

The second graph shows a basic FFT transform of the data

[image: Malware communication intervals and FFT]

Here is the code that I used to generate the FFT transform (found a good write-up at http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-plot-frequency-spectrum-with.html) but still not exactly sure how to apply FFTs to the problem set

```
def plotSpectrum2(k,day_x, day_y):
  """
  Plots a single sided Amplitude spectrum of y(t)
  k = session identifier. combination of user IP and dest domain(s)
  day_x = array of every second in a day
  day_y = array of count of communications from this session each second of the day 
  """
  fig = pylab.figure()
  pylab.subplot(211)

  pylab.plot(day_x,day_y,'k',color='red',linewidth=2)
  pylab.title('Blah')
  pylab.legend(('X'))
  pylab.xlabel=('Time')


  pylab.subplot(212)
  n = len(day_y)
  k = arange(n)

  Fs = 1.0 #sampling rate - once a second
  Ts = 1.0/Fs #sampling interval - at max, collecting once a second
  T = n/Fs
  frq = k/T # two sides frequency range
  frq = frq[range(n/2)] # one side frequency range

  y = fft(day_y)/n
  y = y[range(n/2)]

  pylab.plot(frq,abs(y),'k',color='red',linewidth=2)
```

It looks like specific frequencies are being identified (at first glance, quite a bit different than traffic to google.com for example). I'm stuck trying to figure out how to go from the graph results below to refining the algorithm, and programatically determining if there appears to be underlying frequencies of communication that look more like a machine talking than a human. Any thoughts or online references would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert on this, but I think it might be easier to do this in the time domain. First I would group the data by destination URL. Then I would compute the intervals between requests for these URLs (probably discarding URLs with only a couple of hits from your analysis). You can view these intervals per URL as samples from a statistical distribution. Compute a histogram and see how they the distribution looks like. If the requests come from a human, the intervals should be random (my first guess would be exponentially distributed). If you see that certain intervals (e. g. one hour or one day) appear more often, this might indicate malware calling home. Of course, it could also be some application checking for updates, and the malware could be hidding its tracks by randomizing the time between its calls.

Comment: Good suggestion. That is actually the first thing I tried. I started looking into FFT's because it's difficult to separate out multiple infected boxes behind a single IP address (the intervals between each packet no longer represent a single entity, which throws off the results)